# PrimeNgConfig is not available from primeng/api

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using Primeng (version: ^9.1.3) and was try to implement translation on p-calendar primeng component, which can be done using PrimeNGConfig as per [post](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/i18n), but i am not able to import the module from 'primeng/api' got an error

> Module 'primeng/api' has no exported member PrimeNGConfig

Comment: I think that PrimeNGConfig only is available with Prime version 11. Have you tried to update Prime?

Comment: the upgrade worked for me